# onChangeMonthYear is not working under datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

Hello all I am working on a datepicker. What I need is when I change month or year I should be able to capture it(month/year). Yeah I have seen many answers on SO but none of them worked for, I will display my code here please tell me where I am going wrong. Let me tell you I am using angularjs(mvc). The code I am going to display now is written in angularjs controller,(for some reason I have not used angularjs datepicker), I have used jQuery datepicker, And now I want to access it from angularjs controller

controller code is as follows

```
$("#myCalendar").datepicker({
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month,instance) {
                 alert("h");
             }
        });
```

html page code is:

```
<div class="box-body no-padding">
   <div id="myCalendar" style="width: 100%" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, Please check it properly. Your code is working fine. You can check following  event fired properly.

```
onChangeMonthYear
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/saddam_msp/Xx4GS/233/)

Comment: Yeah its working there, then why on earth its not working on my machine. Can there be a jQuery ui version issue?

Comment: It may possible. Which version you are using.?

Comment: jQuery ui version 1.8